# AutoRotate previous ViewController after dismissing another ViewController at an orientation iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, orientation, autorotate

I have an iPad application with allowed orientations *landscape right* and *landscape left*. I have two `ViewControllers`, let's say `VC1` and `VC2`. On a button click on `VC1`, the `VC2` opens up. Now, if initially the app is in *landscape right* and after opening `VC2` I rotate the device to *landscape left* and come back to `VC1`, the `VC1` is still in *landscape right*.

Flow is something like so:

[image]

How can I make `VC1` autorotate to the orientation of `VC2` on dismissal of `VC2`?

Comment: do you present VC2 ? 
do you have a UITabbarController ?
please explain more to help u  , because the answer relate your view hierarchy

Comment: @MohamadFarhand I have added a picture just to show the flow. I present VC2 on button click on VC1

Comment: i have create a sample project for you and upload it for you !
i haven't any problem .
please test the sample project and notify me
http://uplod.ir/8cu796cdvjif/testRotation.zip.htm

Comment: @MohamadFarhand I cant seem to download it. I tried translating it to english. Can you post some snippet here or maybe a procedure to do it

Comment: sorry :
http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=05693183207263185118

Comment: @MohamadFarhand thanks for the solution. As Iam working with Xamarin, could you please explain the process of achieving this? Iam new to iOS

Comment: does it work  ? 
i didn’t do anything more .
this is the default and normal behavior.

Comment: Where exactly do I add the code for Orientation detection? I couldnt find it in the solution you provided

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103691/discussion-between-mohamad-farhand-and-hello-world).